# German single syllable words with multisyllabic English Translation

Tags: german-to-english, curiosity

Might there be someone who knows of additional monosyllabic German words which translate to a multi-syllabic English word?

My Turn:

```
Der Stau    ==  The trafficjam
```

And my favorite

```
um == around
```

I originally thought `die Achsel` would make this list, but looking closer it looks like its on the higher end of the single syllable spectrum so there may be room for debate.

Comment: Isn't it "traffic jam", two words?

Comment: I find this question a bit difficult, since often, there is no one-to-one translation, but there are several options how to translate a word (depending on the context). To give an example: yes, one translation of _traffic jam_ is _Stau_, but you could also say _Verkehrsstau_. If also seen _jam_ as a translation for _Stau_, which would be a single syllable... So, would you say _any_ possible translation would be a correct answer, as long as the number of syllables are one _vs_ many?

Comment: In addition, there will be multiple possible answers: how will you decide in the end, which is the best?

Comment: (1) Knowing such word pairs is pointless. (2) There are certainly lots of them, which is why this question is too broad. (3) A word may have different translations. For example, depending on the context, _jam_ could be translated to _Stau_, _Marmelade_, _Gedränge_, _Dilemma_ or whatsoever.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich  Pointless for you it might be, but for me it is a pointed question, and I am interested in the result. Because, usually it is the other way round: English tends to be much shorter-worded than German. Knowing examples that go the other way round might at least be entertaining.

Comment: Question: Why *Achsel*? That's a bisyllabic word, to my understanding?

Comment: @Arsak yes, any translation would do as long as the single syllable word is commonly used and found in standard reference materials

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann   The 'ch' sound in Achsel blended with the 'sel' sound to my English speaking ear, but when I thought on it more it seems like two syllables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question asks to be answered through collecting words in a community wiki. Which I hereby create. Knowledgeable folks, come and join!

(I start with those that were mentioned already in the question and first answers)

## Good ones

- All → universe (but also: *space*)
- Amt → agency, office, department
- Angst → anxiety (but also: *fear, angst*)
- arg → severe, terrible, eerie (but also: *bad*)
- auch → also
- auf → onto, upon, open, ... (but also: *on, up, at, to , in*)
- an → upon (but also: *on, at, to, by, in*)
- Bahn → railroad, railway (but also: *train, rail, lane, tram, way*)
- Bauch → stomach, belly (but also: *waist, bunt*)
- bei → nearby
- Berg → mountain (but also: *hill, alp, berg, mount, peak, plane, run*)
- Brät → sausage meat
- Brauch → custom
- Bund → association, covenant, federation, ... (but also: *bunch, league, tie, band, coil*)
- bunt → colourful (but also: *stained, gay*)
- Dampf → vapor
- Deutsch → German
- Dorf → village
- Duft → fragrance, flavor, odor/odour (but also: *smell, scent*)
- dumm → stupid, silly (but also: *dense, dull, dumb*)
- Dunst → vapor
- Eis → ice cream (but also: *ice*)
- Fall → issue, matter (but also: *fall, drop, case*)
- Fass → barrel (but also *cask, drum, butt*)
- fein → subtle, delicate, ... (but also: *fine, nice, keen*)
- Fest → party, festival
- flach → shallow (but also: *flat, plain*)
- Fluss → river
- Forst → forest
- Frau → woman (but also *wife, miss*)
- Fund → finding (but also: *find, trove*)
- gelb → yellow
- Gift → poison, venom, toxin
- Greif → griffin
- hohl → hollow
- Huhn → chicken (but also: *hen, fowl*)
- jäh → precipitous, sudden, abrupt
- Kaff → hicksville, dullsville (but also *dump, chaff*)
- Köln → Cologne
- Kost → diet (but also: *fare, food*)
- Kot → faeces (but also: *dung, dirt, scat*))
- Kraft → power (but also: *force, strength, vigor/vigour, load, vim*)
- Land → country (but also: *land, ground, soil*)
- leer → empty (but also: *blank, void, vain*)
- Mann → husband (but also: *man, male, guy*)
- neu → novel
- oft → often
- Pfand → deposit, forfeit, ... (but also: *pawn, pledge, gauge*)
- reif → mature (but also: ripe*)
- Rind → cattle (but also: *cow*)
- Ruf → reputation (but also: *call, cry, fame, shout, rep, whoop, hoot*)
- sanft → gentle, mellow, ... (but also: *soft, mild, bland, meek, suave*)
- schal → stalely (but also: *flat, stale*)
- Schal → muffler (but also: *scarf, shawl*)
- Schloss → castle (but also: *lock*)
- schwer → heavy (but also: *big, hard, rich*)
- Spatz → sparrow
- Speck → bacon (but also: *flab, speck*)
- Stadt → city (but also: *town, burg*)
- Stall → stable
- steif → rigid (but also: *stiff, prim, firm, taut, stark*)
- Stift → pencil (but also: *pen, giv, nib, peg, bold, nail, spike, stud, pin, ...*)
- Streit → dispute, quarrel (but also: *fight, brawl, clash, strife*)
- streng → rigorous (but also: *strict, stiff, tight, stern, grim*)
- Streu → litter (but also: *mulch*)
- Tang → seaweed (but also: *kelp*)
- Tausch → exchange, tradeoff (but also: *swap*)
- Text → lyrics (but also: *text*)
- Tisch → table (but also: *desk*)
- Turm → tower (but also: *spire, rook*)
- um → around (but also: *at, round, for, to*)
- Vieh → cattle (but also: *brute, stock*)
- Wald → forest (but also: *wood(s)*)
- Wanst → belly (but also: *paunch*)
- weg → away (but also: *far, off*)
- Weib → woman
- Wurst → sausage (but also: *link, snag*)
- Wut → fury, anger (but also: *rage, ire, wrath*)
- Zoff → trouble
- Zoll → customs
- Zorn → anger (but also: *rage, ire, wrath*)

## More questionable ones

- Stau → traffic jam; but: Verkehrsstau
- Klo → toilet; but: loo
- Balg → bellows; but only in this meaning; many other meanings of *Balg* have monosyllabic English solutions (brat, felt, skin, bag, pod...); also bellows = *Blasebalg*
- Schmand → sour cream (unless you find *cream* sufficient; but from a German perspective *cream* is too unspecific as it covers also *süße Sahne*, and for us *saure Sahne* and *süße Sahne* are things from two different universes)

Note: Now that the list has become surprisingly long, it seems the idea of "*good ones* versus *questionable ones*" does not hold water. The idea was to separate those that have definitely no monosyllabic equivalent in English ("good ones") from those that have both multisyllabic and monosyllabic equivalents ("not so good ones") But as almost every word in a language has multiple equivalents in a target language, depending on meaning and context, it is not really a practical criterion: one can open up the semantical field and will eventually find a monosyllabism also for those words that initially seem "good". I consider merging the two lists into one...  (Christian)

Answer (score 2):

I got another one
German: Das Huhn
English: Chicken